# If $A$ and $B$ be two non-singular matrices of order $3$ such that $2A+3BB^{T}=I$ and $B^{-1}=A^{T}$, then determine the value of the following:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

> If $A$ and $B$ be two non-singular matrices of order $3$ such that $2A+3BB^{T}=I$ and $B^{-1}=A^{T}$, then determine the value of the following:
>
> (i) $\det\left(B^{T}-2B+3B^{3}+3BA\right)$
>
> (ii) $\det\left(A^{-1}-3B^{3}\right)$
>
> (iii) $\text{trace}\left(A^{-1}+I-AB-3B^{3}\right)$

**My Attempt:**

Given $2A+3BB^{T}=I$

Taking transpose $2A^{T}+3BB^{T}=I$

So on subtracting we get $A=A^{T}$ i.e. $A$ is symmetric

Given that, $B^{-1}=A^{T}=A$ and thus $AB=BA=I$

Now, all I need to get the answers to the above questions is to somehow prove that $B$ is also symmetric i.e. $B^{T}=B$

$AB=I$

$B^TA^T=I$

$B^TB^{-1}=I$

$B^T=B$

Given that $2A+3BB^T=I$

$2B^{-1}+3B^2=I$

$B-3B^3=2I$

Thus,$B^T-2B+3B^3+3BA=B-2B+3B^3+3I=3B^3-B+3I=-2I+3I=I$

Also, $A^{-1}+I-AB-3B^3=A^{-1}-3B^3=B-3B^3=2I$

Comment: Are they real matrices?

Comment: Yes.The matrices are real.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume $A,B$ real matrices.

Recall the Spectral Real Theorem:

> A matrix $A$ is symmetric if and only if it is orthogonally diagonalizable.

The matrix $BB^T$ is symmetric so there exists $M\in O(3)$ such that $MBB^TM^T = D$ with $D$ diagonal matrix. Now:
\begin{gather}
2A+3BB^T=I\\
M(2A+3BB^T)M^T=I\\
MAM^T = \frac{1}{2}(I-3D)
\end{gather}
So $A$ is orhogonally diagonalizable and thanks to the spectral theorem it is symmetric.

---

**Edit**: This part does not require the real spectral theorem. Take simply the transpose of the first equality in the hypotesis. This show that $A$ is symmetric.

---

Now we have $B^{-1}=A^T = A$ and hence $B=A^{-1}$ and $B$ is also symmetric. The first hypotesis become:
\begin{equation}
2B^{-1}+3B^2=I
\end{equation}
multiplicand LHS and RHS by $B$ we have:
\begin{equation}
3B^3-B+2I=0
\end{equation}
Denoting with $m_B(T)$ the minimal polynomial of $B$, we have that $m_B(t)$ divides $(3t^3-t+2)=(t+1)(3t^2-3t+2)$ and, since $B$ is diagonalizable, we have $m_B(t)=(t+1)$. So $B$ has to be the matrix $-I$ and now:
\begin{gather}
\det(B^T-2B+3B^3+3BA)=\det(-I + 2I - 3I + 3I) = \det(I) = 1\\
\det(A^{-1}-3B^3)=\det(-I+3I) = 2^3\det(I) = 8\\
\text{trace}(A^{-1}+I-AB-3B^3) = \text{trace}(-I+I-I+3I) = \text{trace}(2I) = 6
\end{gather}